# Multi Agent Sokoban Search Solvers state of the art

Tags: research, intelligent-agent, multi-agent-systems

<sub>I also asked this question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109807/multi-agent-sokoban-solvers-state-of-the-art) but I'm repeating it on this SE because I feel it is more relevant. No intention to spam.</sub>

I am researching into coding a solver for a variant of the [Sokoban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) game with multiple agents, restrictions (eg. colors of stones, goals) and relaxations (push AND pull possible, etc.)

By researching online I have found classic papers in the field, like the Rolling Stone paper (by Andreas Junghanns and Jonathan Schaeffer) and *Sokoban: Enhancing general single-agent search methods using domain knowledge* from the same authors.

These solutions seem to be outdated and I am currently structuring my solver per the notes of the two most performant solvers: [YASS](http://www.sokobano.de/wiki/index.php?title=Sokoban_solver_%22scribbles%22_by_Brian_Damgaard_about_the_YASS_solver) and [Sokolution](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109807/multi-agent-sokoban-solvers-state-of-the-art).

From the research, I've done these two seem to be my best bet.

It is apparent that they are not enough by themselves to solve a multi-agent environment. Those solvers are made for a single agent. So far, I have failed to find useful multi-agent proposals.

In this context, my question is:

1. What can be considered state-of-the-art in order to:

   - coordinate multiple agents with different goals, and
   - plug a solver's solution in and validate/edit it?
2. What are some search terms I can use to research this further?

Thank you very much